# How to make Alt+Tab return to same application window as last used (Unity)

Tags: 14.04, unity, application-switcher

Using <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>Tab</kbd> normally does what I want; it groups windows from the same application. If I want to switch between windows of one and the same application, I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>`</kbd>

However, if I have multiple terminal windows open (for example), and I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to another application, and then switch back to the terminal, another terminal window is in front than the last one.

How do I force it to always return to the same application window, like gnome 3 does?

Ubuntu 14.04 unity.

Comment: Is one of these options a solution to you? http://askubuntu.com/a/569481/72216

Comment: No not really, unless I customise that script to do what I want ... in which case how would I know the last switched application that's not the current one in python?

Comment: @JacobVlijm That's not quite what I want, it brings forward _all_ the windows of an application, I just want to bring forwards the most recent window of an application

Comment: @JacobVlijm I've tried the script in Option 2, it says `File "./a.py", line 37, in <module>
arg = apps[0]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: I saved it as a.py and ran it from the command line and from a keyboard shortcut (which did nothing). I may have made a mistake in implementing it I'm not sure. I am on 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below a script that switches through application windows. It remembers the last used (= frontmost) window of all running applications, bypassing other windows of the same application.

The script is based on the same principle as the scripts [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/569481/72216), but since the script only runs when a key combination is pressed, the last used window  (per application) needs to be stored and read outside the script(-'s memory).

#### How to use

- The script uses `wmctrl`

  ```
    sudo apt-get install wmctrl
  ```
- Copy the script below into an empty file, same it as `alternative_switcher.py`
- Add it to a shortcut key combination: Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts".
  Click the "+" and add the command:

  ```
    python3 /path/to/alternative_switcher.py
  ```
- Use it as an alternative switcher with your key combination.

#### Note

The script switches among "normal" application windows, as defined as: "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL" in the output of the `xprop -id <window_id>` command. That means that dialogue windows will be excluded from the window list, as well as `Idle` windows for example, which have pid 0.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import getpass

home = os.environ["HOME"]
lastdir = home+"/.config/alternative_switcher"; wlist = lastdir+"/"+"wlist.txt"

def get(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", command]).decode("utf-8")

def get_frontmost():
    cmd = "xprop -root"
    frontmost = [l for l in get(cmd).splitlines() if\
                 "ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)" in l][0].split()[-1]
    return frontmost[:2]+"0"+frontmost[2:]
# read last used windowlist
if not os.path.exists(lastdir):
    os.makedirs(lastdir)
try:
    with open(wlist) as src:
        windowlist = eval(src.read())
except (FileNotFoundError, SyntaxError):
    windowlist = []
# creating window list: id, application name
w_data = [l.split()[0:7] for l in get("wmctrl -lpG").splitlines()]
[windowlist.remove(w) for w in windowlist if not w[1] in [data[0] for data in w_data]]
windows = [[get("ps -u "+getpass.getuser()+" | grep "+w[2]).split()[-1], w[0]]
           for w in w_data if "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL" in get("xprop -id "+w[0])]
# get frontmost window + application
frontmost = [data for data in windows if data[1] == get_frontmost()][0]
[windowlist.remove(item) for item in windowlist if item[0] == frontmost[0]]
# add frontmost to  windowlist of last-used application windows
windowlist.insert(0, frontmost)
current_app = frontmost[0]
# determine next application
apps = sorted(set([w[0] for w in windows]))
next_app_i = apps.index(current_app)+1
if next_app_i == len(apps):
    next_app_i = 0
next_app = apps[next_app_i]
# find matching window to raise
try:
    next_w = [w[1] for w in windowlist if w[0] == next_app][0]
except IndexError:
    next_w = [w[1] for w in windows  if w[0] == next_app][0]
# write last- window list
with open(wlist, "wt") as out:
    out.write(str(windowlist))
# raise next window
cmd = "wmctrl -ia "+next_w
subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
```

Comment: Thanks! This is nearly correct... except it doesn't cycle through the most recently opened applications first like Alt + Tab does - though there is a problem with that in that it would forever cycle between two applications... unless more functionality was added so it stays up while you hold the alt tab for example.

Comment: @texasflood It would be a bad idea to do in a script like this, since only switching between the last two applications would limit the functionality quite. With Alt+Tab it is no problem, since you have the visual overview and can escape from the cycle. I cannot change the functionality of Alt+Tab, only offer a nearby solution.

Comment: @texasflood fixed a small bug on resuming after closing windows.