# Is there any way to open all instances of a particular application without having to click on its icon multiple times?

Tags: unity, desktop-environments

I'm using Unity. If there's any desktop version out there that supports this I'd be curious to know about it.

For example, say I have 3 terminals open. Whenever I click on the terminal icon on the taskbar, Ubuntu opens the last terminal I opened manually. If I click on the icon again, it shows me all of the terminals open and I can then open another manually.

Is there any way to see all of the terminals at once without having to open each one separately? This gets incredibly cumbersome when I have 3 or 4 terminals open.

Comment: Tried to hold shift when click on it?

Comment: @xangua That seems to just open a new instance of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show all windows of an application?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/446521/how-to-show-all-windows-of-an-application)

Comment: Option 3 of this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/569481/72216 is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Matthew, just curious, but did you manage?

Answer (score 0):

"If there's any desktop version out there that supports this I'd be curious to know about it."

I just recently switched from using lightdm to using gdm.  I have not fully decided which one I prefer yet, and may yet go back to lightdm.  One advantage of gdm: when you click on "Activities" at the top left hand corner, it shows not only your programs which you have marked as favorites on the left, but also shows ALL windows that are open.  It shows every instance of terminal, every instance of Firefox, and so on, and you can choose which one to select.  This isn't exactly what you're asking for, but it does get all the open windows in one click.  You may want to try gdm to see if you like it.

In order to try gdm, open a Terminal.  Use the following command:

> sudo apt-get install gdm

Once you have it, it will inform you that there are multiple instances of a display manager installed.  Select OK by hitting Enter (if that doesn't work try Space).  Then it will ask you which to use as your default.  Choose gdm with the arrow keys and hit Enter again.  **There are a few ways to get it to switch to gdm now.  I find that the way that is the least buggy is to simply reboot your computer**; if you've selected gdm as your default, it will automatically boot into gdm.  The other way is to enter into the Terminal:

> sudo service gdm restart

The login screen will look different in gdm, but it's self-explanatory.

If you decide that you would rather go back to lightdm, I find that the simplest way to get back to it is to prompt the choice for which one should be used as default again by using the following commands:

> sudo apt-get remove lightdm
>
> sudo apt-get install lightdm

Once lightdm is reinstalled, it will ask you which one you want as your default; choose lightdm.  You can then, from within lightdm, remove gdm with:

> sudo apt-get remove gdm

I do not recommend removing gdm from within gdm, nor removing lightdm (should you decide you prefer gdm) from within lightdm.