How to raise all windows of a single application from the dock?
Upgraded to 24.04LTS and was surprised to find that the simple action of selecting a running application from the dock does not show all the open windows as it did in the 20.04LTS
How can I get back that functionality?
I am often running Chrome and have opened a separate Developers Tools window and placed it on a separate monitor. Ideally I want to "raise" both windows when I click on the Chrome icon on the dock and not first surface one window and then on a second click show the app spread.
I have passed through my angry-man-shakes-fist-at-cloud phase and I am genuinely interested why no on else seems to be be affected by this.
There are other mutli-window and multi-instance apps that I use in a similar way that are negatively affected. So all the bind script to key solutions are out, due to targeting a single named application.

Have you seen this topic which I think discusses your issue? https://askubuntu.com/questions/446521/how-to-show-raise-all-windows-of-an-application There does not seem to be a solution there though, only workarounds/scripts/hotkeys etc.
